# Using copyProperties() instead of custom Gson serializer - does worth it?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class with multiple fields, some of them has bidirectional relationships with other classes. So because of the links between classes, I can't serialize the class directly, because it'll throw a StackOverflowError.

What I did was to create a "SimpleClass" object without the linked fields, and I used `copyProperties` to copy some of the fields from the original class to the "simplified" and I serialized that.

Here is an example:

```java
List<Project> projects  = projectRepository.findAllByCompany_IdOrderByDueDateAsc(id, PageRequest.of(page, limit));
Collection<SimpleProjectList> simpleProjects = new ArrayList<>();
projects.forEach(project -> {
    SimpleProjectList simpleProjectList = new SimpleProjectList();
    copyProperties(project, simpleProjectList);
    simpleProjects.add(simpleProjectList);
});
```

The "Project" class has all of the fields (including the bidirectional), and the "SimpleProjectList" do not have these, just some basic fields. (eg. projectName, dueDate, projectId, etc.)

**So this is just simply leaves out the problematic bidirectional fields. It actually works, but I'm wondering if there's any other (probably faster) option.**

Is this okay or there's a much more effective solution for this?

Comment: If you want to use Java serialization, declare the link fields `transient` and they won't be serialized, thus avoiding the StackOverflowError.

Comment: As I experienced, when a field is transient, I cannot use setters and getters with it. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Uh, no that can't be right.  Show an example if you are having problems.

Comment: Anyways, it seems to Spring cant find the fields either.
```Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: io.system.backend.model.Client.company in io.system.backend.model.Company.clients```
because in the Client class the company field is transient

Comment: Jackson has a `@JsonIgnore` field level annotation for this. Looks like gson has an `@Expose` annotation for the same purpose but it works the other way round

Comment: 1) Rename your `SimpleProjectList` to either `SimpleProject` or `ProjectDto` ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object ). 2) `copyProperties` comes from `BeanUtils`? Well, don't do that because the `ProjectDto` has to match property names to make it work that is not always a good thing. Simply create a factory method in the `ProjectDto` class and manually copy the fields you need in the outcome. 3) Here you can remap related entities to IDs (I don't think `BeanUtils` can do that) not losing the relation information.

Comment: 4) If you think that remapping from A to B is "boring", there are tools helping you to accomplish it like https://mapstruct.org/ . 5) Don't use `forEach` like that: first, it's unordered so you may even end up in "random" order, use either the `for` statement that does not introduce another function scope, or `.map(ProjectDto::fromEntity)` with `collect(Collectors.toList())` to generate the result list in the idiomatic way.

Comment: 6) I've suggested untagging this question as `gson` since this a question for a common back-end issue, not the library itself.